# Получить все картинки из Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть сайт-казино, реализованный с помощью **canvas**. Как можно получить все картинки, используемые этим **canvas'ом**? Простите, что без кода, т.к. идей совсем нет

Comment: сайт или грузит эти картинки в рантайм или содержит их в скрипте, в самом тяжелом случае может генерировать их в рантайм

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, можно чуть подробнее?) Вы имеете ввиду, что они приходят с сервера?

Comment: я описал 3 варианта, может и с сервера